# How to logstash from elasticsearch with specific _type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash (6.8.1) configuration file like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
    index => "myindex"
    codec => "json"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9300" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

However, the es in port 9200 is 5.x, and the es in port 9300 is 6.x.
Moreover, the es in port 9200 has multiple "types".

Since es 6.x has only one "type", I need something like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
    user => ""
    password => ""
    index => "myindex"
    document_type => "mytype"  <--- like this
    codec => "json"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
```

How can I realize this?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Where you want the "type" in input or output ? It is unclear, however for input I have shared my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use `elasticsearch-dump` to realize this operation:

```
docker run --net=host --rm -it docker.io/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump \
    --input=http://user:password@input-es:9200 \
    --input-index=my-user-index/my-user-type \
    --output=http://user:password@output-es:9200 \
    --output-index=my-user-index \
    --type=mapping
```

PS: to migrate data, use option `--type=data`

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you an example of jenkins logstash configuration.

Did you mean this:

```
input {
  file {
     path => "/var/log/jenkins/*"
     type => "jenkins-server"
     start_position => "beginning"
 } 
}
  filter 
 {
      if [type] == "jenkins-server" {
          mutate {
              add_field => ["@message_type", "jenkins"]
              add_field => ["@message", "%{message}"]
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Does this "type" meas a type in logstash, rather than the _type in elasticsearch?
For example, the _type in es is like something below:
```
{
  "_index" : "my-user-index",
  "_type" : "my-user-type",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "this ia a name",
    "age" : 12
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. type in Logstash is same to _type in ES. Both of them perform same which is indexing in order to make searching by type name fast.